# Running unix command in .cpp file on Xcode(MAC) other than system( ) method

Tags: macos

Need to run this "system/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend" executable command in .cpp file in Xcode(MAC). Propose a method otherthan system().

Comment: You say "Xcode(MAC)" and yet the question is tagged "ios"?

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, if you want to go lower level than system, you could use any of the calls in [exec(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/exec.3.html).

Comment: none of the exec() works with that...can it be there any other way??

Comment: This "system/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend" working on 10.6 and 10.8, but not on 10.7???(works from terminal) when i tried to launch thru my app. Expecting Possible solutions!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [NSTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstask) if you're making a Cocoa app. If you're using Swift, it's  called Process instead.